# How to put conditions on an eager loading without Join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I know the has been asked before, but I can't figure out how to do it.  I'm trying to eager load the influences on questions and answers, but only the current users, think of it as checking if a user has voted for the item.... An event is the base item.  I'd like to do this preferably without joins.  My models look like:

```
Event has many Questions
Question has many Answers

Event has many influences
Question has many influences
Answer has many influences
```

What I've tried is:

```
event.questions.includes(:answers, :influences)
```

But this gets All the influences, not just the current_users. I also tried scoping that influences, but that doesn't seem to work.. and I had a real hard time trying to define a 'users_influences' has_many association by which I could use instead of influences..

I'd like to load the users influences so they are available to, questions, and answers in an eager loaded fashion.. to clarify this influences table is a bit like a line-item, connecting a user to these other various entities.. is this possible without a join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monkey patch the `ActiveRecord::Base` in `configuration\initializers\monkey_patches.rb`

```
class ActiveRecord::Base

  # Use thread local variables to store the context.
  def self.current_user=user
    Thread.current[:current_user]= user
  end

  def self.current_user
    Thread.current[:current_user]
  end

  def current_user
    ActiveRecord::Base.current_user
  end

end
```

Add a `before_filter` in your `application_controller.rb` to set the current user within the request context.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :init_app_request

  def init_app_request
    ActiveRecord::Base.current_user = current_user # set the current user
  end
end
```

Now modify your association in `Question` model. Add a new association called `current_user_influences` that will filter influences based on current user.

```
class Question

  has_many :influences,

  # use single quotes for the `conditions` string to avoid interpolating
  # the string during class loading.

  has_many :current_user_influences, :class_name => "Influence",
             :conditions => '#{current_user_check}' 

  def current_user_check
    current_user ? "influences.user_id = #{current_user.id} " : ""
  end
end
```

Now you can eager-load `current_user_influences`:

```
questions =event.questions.includes(:answers, :current_user_influences)
# influences pertaining to the current user
questions.first.current_user_influences
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, what an awesome answer.  You are an asset to this community.  Thanks.

Comment: @Inc1982 can you let me know if the solution worked for you? I air coded the solution. I would like to update the answer if there are  errors in the current solution.

Comment: @HarishShetty, just wonder why you Thread.current instead of instance variable? Any differences?

Comment: Another solution is to use default scope with current_user on those models.

Comment: @Chamnap, you can either use static variable OR thread local variable for storing the current user.
This way, the current user is accessible to any object within the controller request context. Using thread local variable for current user ensures that the variable in not overwritten in a multi-threaded deployment.(eg: JRuby/Rails4 etc)

Comment: It means that if I use instance variable to store, will it be overwritten? Every object has its instance variables. How could it get overwritten?

Comment: If you use an instance variable it will not be overwritten(unless you pass it around accross requests). 
This means you need to set the current user to all the objects that needs access to the current user. Typically, the current user is  same within a request context hence there is no need to set it in the object context. If you don't mind setting it before every call you can do so. But it will be a difficult code to maintain as every programmer in the group has to remember to set the current user.